# How to convert Negative Amount to Positive and Positive amount to negative in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database I have a Transaction table.

- If a **payment is made** to merchant then it records amount in **negative value**.
- If we **receive refunds** then it records payment in **positive value**.

[image]

How can I convert negatives to positive and Positive to negative while querying this table ?

Thank you

Comment: Multiply the number by -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select with a multiply by -1 expression

```
SELECT TransactionId, InvoiceId, Amount * -1 FROM Transaction
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked and also subtracting 0 also worked. now which is the best practice?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a best practice... I find * -1 more intuitive and easier to recognize in code, but they accomplish the same task